# Limiting the effect of Copy Rotation constraints on a single axis. Having issues with axis flipping

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints, bone.constraints

As part of a larger rig, I'm trying to achieve the effect where a deformation bone copies the location of a root bone, and the rotation in the Y&Z axis, but when rotated on the X axis only copies the rotation by 25%.

I'm having some very strange behaviour when the root bone goes beyond 180, the axis flips.

I've tried both a Copy Rotation with limited influence, and also a Transformation constraint where the X axis is mapped from -360/360 to -90/90. Both have the same issue. I've also tried different rotation modes changing between Quaternion and Euler, no change. Hoping someone can help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can fix it, so maybe look into drivers instead?

Comment: Is there a reason copy rotation is in world coordinates? Getting the rotation from 1 bone and transforming the rotation relative to that bones as well might be causing this behaviour.